# Ubuntu 12.04 video issue on Dell Inspiron 1100

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, inspiron

I have an old clunker - Dell Inspiron 1100 with A32 BIOS.
I managed to install correctly from a USB drive, and the screen showed graphics in full natice 1024 x 768 - as did the 'try from USB' Ubuntu option.
Once I committed to a full install on the HDD, the video resolution comes up as 640 x 480 with no other resolutions to change to full screen.
Does anyone have some advice to allow the full LCD panel to be used?

Thanks for reading
Ed

Answer (score 2):

## Ubuntu and Dell Inspiron 1100

Change Video Memory in BIOS setup:
Make sure your Dell Inspiron 1100 notebook has been upgraded to the A32 BIOS.
When you start your computer, hit F2 to enter Setup.
Press Alt-P (Turn the page) until you get to the page with the video memory (might be page 6, and might be listed as UMA (it’s actually “VMA”) size).
Change the video memory from 1MB to 8MB.
Reboot.

Once you've installed Ubuntu and you reboot, press Escape at the GRUB loader (it's the screen right after your bios initializes). Ubuntu Karmic (9.10) and higher will need to press and hold the left Shift key instead of Escape.
Press e to edit the first kernel displayed.
Find the line ending with "quiet splash". Add your boot option before these key words - i.e. so the line looks like ..."nomodeset quiet splash".
Then press CTRL + X to boot.

To permanent this to GRUB2, you should add this option to /etc/default/grub, from a command prompt (terminal):

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

The suggested options that I have found are hardware specific. Here is a list:

- Older Intel video card: i915.modeset=1 or i915.modeset=0
- nVidia: nomodeset
- Generic: xforcevesa

Then add "i915.modeset=0" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.modeset=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Save your changes and you should get proper graphics on each reboot after doing:

```
sudo update-grub
```

To fully utilize the graphics, you also need to tweak xorg.conf:

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Here is an example of what you should consider/what I have in mine, everything might not be needed/be legacy:

```
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf (xorg X Window System server configuration file)
#
# Edit this file with caution, and see the /etc/X11/xorg.conf manual page.
# (Type "man /etc/X11/xorg.conf" at the shell prompt.)
#
# This file is automatically updated on xserver-xorg package upgrades *only*
# if it has not been modified since the last upgrade of the xserver-xorg
# package.
#

Section "Module"
    Load    "GLcore"
    Load    "i2c"
    Load    "bitmap"
    Load    "ddc"
    Load    "dri"
    Load    "extmod"
    Load    "freetype"
    Load    "glx"
    Load    "int10"
    Load    "type1"
    Load    "vbe"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Corporation 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device"
    Driver      "i810"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Generic Monitor"
    ModelName   "Dell 1024x768 Laptop Display Panel"
    Option      "DPMS"
        HorizSync   31.5-48.5
    VertRefresh 59-75
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Device      "Intel Corporation 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device"
    Monitor     "Generic Monitor"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth       1
        Modes       "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth       4
        Modes       "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth       8
        Modes       "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth       15
        Modes       "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth       16
        Modes       "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes       "1024x768" "800x600" "640x480"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier  "Default Layout"
    Screen      "Default Screen"
EndSection

Section "DRI"
    Mode    0666
EndSection

# End /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

I also strongly recommend running Unity 2D on this machine.
At login prompt, click on the Ubuntu logo after your name and choose "Ubuntu 2D".

I also recommend making the icons smaller:
http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/06/resize-unity-2d-launcher-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

After all this, you should now be able to reboot into your nicely working Ubuntu installation. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to get this working with Ubuntu 13.04 and have been going crazy, nothing is consistently working!

I tried the suggested settings of:

```
nomodeset
i915.modeset=0
i915.modeset=1
```

The `nomodeset` would boot into a working graphical screen about 1 time in every three reboots. The others wouldn't work at all.

Finally, I changed the settings to explicitly set the VGA mode at boot and have yet to have a failure!

This is my configuration from `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off vga=792"
```

Remember to run the `update-grub` after making the change.

(more information on the Linux Video Modes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Linux_video_mode_numbers )

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

After going through these instructions very carefully and not getting the desired result I found this to work much better.

Instead of changing the version of grub in the `/etc/default` folder, I had to change it in the `boot/grub` folder and make sure the quotes (`"`) are included in that location. Also, the `=1` worked rather than the `=0` so it should read as:

```
"quiet splash i915.modeset=1"
```

Answer (score 1):

With xubuntu 14.04, I found that setting vga=792 as above worked for me, however I also noted a message that reported that the `vga=792` parameter is deprecated. I subsequently found a more modern solution which I cribbed from the `/etc/default/grub` file of a manjaro live cd. I added the following two lines to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768

GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

(Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub`)

This worked fine. I also found that replacing `"=1024x768"` by `"=auto"` in the first line above worked as well.

I hope this information may be helpful to others wrestling with this old clunker.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Ubuntu 17.04 on Dell Inspiron 1100 (82845GL).  Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub`.  This is largely a re-telling of the story mentioned above, but it's been verified on Ubuntu 17.04.

I finally got something working late yesterday.  It took surprisingly few characters... but which ones?

```
stupid ~ 148# rcsdiff -r1.1 /etc/default/grub
===================================================================
RCS file: /etc/default/RCS/grub,v
retrieving revision 1.1
diff -r1.1 /etc/default/grub
11c11
< GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
---
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off vga=auto"
25a26,27
> GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
> GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
stupid ~ 149#
```